# Does limit exist at zero?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, infinity

We know for a limit to exist the LHL and RHL should both be finite and equal or if they are infinite then both should tend towards positive infinity or both towards negetive infinity.

So my question is, if I define a function as
$$
F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
|\ln(-x)|, & \text{for }x<0\\
1/x,& \text{for }x>0
\end{cases}
$$
Then does $\lim_{x\to 0}F(x)$ exist?

Comment: Well, what happens when you test $F(x)$ and $F(-x)$ for small values of $x>0$? Say, $x=1/n$ where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @Michael it would give me the same result as earlier just in a mirrored way! I didn't get why you want me to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \lvert \ln (x) \rvert = \infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$$

Whether this limit really *exists* is a matter of convention. Remember that $\infty$ is just a convenient shorthand for saying that the function grows indefinitely, i.e. it doesn't "tend" to any particular point which is what we define a limit to be. This is why most mathematicians would say that the limit of your function does *not* exist. In some fields, however, (and judging by the criteria you mention in your post this seems to be the case for you) infinite limits are said to exist. Your personal mileage may vary, so I suggest you stick with the definitions that have been provided to you and abide by that.

Comment: @GouravM Suppose that you define $f(x) = \frac{-1}{|x|} : x \neq 0.$  Then, as $x \to 0,$ both ln$(x)$ and $f(x)$ go to $-\infty.$  **Despite** this, their **limits are not equal** at zero, because neither limit exists at $x=0$.  $\infty$ is not a number but rather a symbol for unbounded growth.

Comment: It's mod of ln x.

Comment: @user2661923 can limits be non finite?

Comment: @GouravM to the best of my knowledge, no they can not.  Think about what would happen to the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of a limit if such a thing were allowed.

Comment: @user2661923 can't $\epsilon$ be infinite? I didn't know Cauchy definition before though. In one of my high school ref book it's mentioned limits can be infinite, and it also has the particular eg of 1/|x| where at x-->0 it approaches + infinity.

Comment: @user2661923 You could say "converging to $\pm\infty$" using the [topology of the extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) (that article's description of the topology is not as complete as I would like it to be), but I hardly think that this is what Gourav is going for.

Comment: @GouravM my bad, careless of me not to see the modulus! I've edited my answer to reflect this. Hope this helps

Comment: @GouravM $\varepsilon$ can't be infinite - it can be any positive number, no matter how large. Note that the definition of a (positively) infinite limit differs from that of a regular limit: we say $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$ iff for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $N>0$ such that $0 < \lvert x - a\rvert < N \implies f(x)>M$.